# Can't remove a mailbox

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

I've got a mailbox that I wish to remove. However the error message I get is as follows.

> The mailbox associated to a user or a queue cannot be deleted.

However, I can't see what user/queue that might be locking it. The only thing I can think of is the *Regarding* lookup but it's disabled and can't be set to anything else...

We have a new person on a team and I told them to go nuts but those nuts they've created are weird because I can't see how to remedy that (if the issue's got to do with *Regarding* at all...)

I've tried activating/deactivating, resending the test mail, adding/removing a server profile etc. Mor eor less, anything that I could... The only hit that I found of value (and that's an exaggeration) was [some guy's vague suggestions](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/143832.aspx)...

[image]

Comment: Have you tried looking around in the CRM database? Wouldn't be the solution, but might lead you in the right direction.

Comment: Konrad, exact same issue here. Can't send email because an inactive mailbox is associated to a user. Can't disassociate from user because field is inactive. Can't delete mailbox because associated to a user. Can't enable mailbox, don't know why (maybe because there is *also* an active mailbox associated). I will post answer if I ever find it

Comment: We ended up removing server profiles and all the other mail related settings as routers and such. **Then**, it became possible to get rid of what we didn't want to keep. If you find a smoother solution, you're most welcome to post it here.

Comment: @Kye I don't recall seeing your comment until now. Checking the database is only possible when on-premise and I'd like to see a solution that works for on-line as well.

Answer (score 0):

The Best Answer To this Question Is Mailboxes are dependent on queues and user records but you can’t delete these.
But There Is Another Way To do this action But this Action Is Not Recommended By Microsoft. The Solution Is You Can do With SQL Query and Actually you can Update users and queues and clear out the mailbox field, then Mailboxes Record can be deleted.

```
//First Check Your Primary User Table to See The Records You Want To Delete and Backup from that

select s.DefaultMailbox
from SystemUserBase s

//Like Past Step See This Records And Back it up
select s.DefaultMailbox
from SystemUserBase s

//This Is Primary View For CRM User Like Other Step BackUp Records
select sv.DefaultMailbox, sv.DefaultMailboxName
from SystemUser sv

//And This Is Last Table You Want For This Action This Is queue Table
select q.DefaultMailbox
from QueueBase q

//Then Update This Columns In Tables
update QueueBase
set DefaultMailbox = null

update SystemUser
set DefaultMailbox = null , DefaultMailboxName = null

update SystemUserBase
set DefaultMailbox = null
```

after this queries now you can delete mailboxes 
Hope I Helped You